# Examine for conditional and absolute convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

The problem:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt[4]{n^2+n+1} $$

What I've done trying the root ratio test:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{\sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt[4]{n^2+2n+1+n+2}}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt[4]{n^2+n+1}}|<1 $$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{\sqrt{n+2} - \sqrt[4]{n^2+3n+3}}{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt[4]{n^2+n+1}} |<1$$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} |\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}ln(n+2)} - e^{\frac{1}{4}ln(n^2+3n+3)}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}ln(n+2)} - e^{\frac{1}{4}ln(n^2+3n+3)}}|<1 $$

The question:

I don't know where to go from here. Maybe the criteria I am using is wrong. I think it could be solved if we compare it with something, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 3):

The given series has positive terms, so conditional and absolute convergence coincide.
Given that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt[4]{n^2+n+1}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}=\frac{1}{4}
$$
and the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
is not convergent, then (by the [Limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test)) also the given series is not convergent.